# How may I wrap a word in sublime text 3 with a $ sign

Tags: latex, sublimetext3

I am using latex on Sublime text 3; I would like to put $ sign in a wrap way around the highlighted text. For example, I have a character say

X_{d}

I would like it to do a keyboard shortcut that prints a $ sign before it and after it. How may I do so when I press on `alt-shift-w` I get

```
<p>X_{d}</p>
```

Is there a way to get $?

like $X_{d}$ rather than `<p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding the following to your User keybindings:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+w"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "contents": "\\$${1:$SELECTION}\\$" },
    "context": [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex" },
    ]
},
```

---

To make it reversible, you'll need to write a Python plugin, as the functionality isn't built in to ST:

- Tools menu -> Developer -> New Plugin...
- Select all and replace with the following

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import re


class TextAroundSelectionEventListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_query_context(self, view, key, operator, operand, match_all):
        if key not in ('text_preceding_selection', 'text_following_selection'):
            return None

        match = False
        for sel in view.sel():
            line = view.line(sel)
            before_sel = sublime.Region(line.begin(), sel.begin())
            after_sel = sublime.Region(sel.end(), line.end())
            check_region = before_sel if key == 'text_preceding_selection' else after_sel

            if operator in (sublime.OP_EQUAL, sublime.OP_NOT_EQUAL):
                match = view.substr(check_region) == operand
                if operator == sublime.OP_NOT_EQUAL:
                    match = not match
            else:
                if operator in (sublime.OP_REGEX_MATCH, sublime.OP_NOT_REGEX_MATCH):
                    operand += r'$'
                method = re.match if operator in (sublime.OP_REGEX_MATCH, sublime.OP_NOT_REGEX_MATCH) else re.search
                try:
                    match = bool(method(operand, view.substr(check_region)))
                except re.error as e:
                    print('error in keybinding context operand "' + str(operand) + '" for key "' + key + '":', e)
                    return None
                if operator in (sublime.OP_NOT_REGEX_MATCH, sublime.OP_NOT_REGEX_CONTAINS):
                    match = not match

            if match != match_all:
                return match
        return match


class TrimCharsAroundSelection(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, **kwargs):
        chars_to_trim = kwargs.get('chars_to_trim', 1)
        for sel in reversed(self.view.sel()):
            self.view.replace(edit, sublime.Region(sel.end(), sel.end() + chars_to_trim), '')
            self.view.replace(edit, sublime.Region(sel.begin() - chars_to_trim, sel.begin()), '')
```

- Save in the folder ST suggests (`Packages/User/`) as `text_around_sel.py`

Then, use the following keybindings:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+w"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "contents": "\\$${1:$SELECTION}\\$" },
    "context": [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex" },
        { "key": "text_preceding_selection", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "\\$$" },
        { "key": "text_following_selection", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "^\\$" },
    ]
},
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+w"], "command": "trim_chars_around_selection", "args": { "chars_to_trim": 1 },
    "context": [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex" },
        { "key": "text_preceding_selection", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\$$" },
        { "key": "text_following_selection", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\$" },
    ]
},
```

---

Explanation and reasoning:

- [The `preceding_text` and `following_text` contexts that are built in to ST always include the selected text](https://github.com/guillermooo/sublime-undocs/blob/263b2d02220f113d107b25532649a1eee355aef5/source/reference/key_bindings.rst), no matter where the text selection caret is, making it no use for detecting text *around/outside* the selection.
- (If the selection included the dollars at either end, it would be possible without creating any new context listeners, by using the `text` key, and `^` and `$` anchors.)
- Therefore, we need to write our own contexts that will correctly ignore the selection. Unfortunately, limitations in Sublime's (Find) API mean that we have to use Python's `re` module to do this, which is a much less powerful regex engine - though for the purposes of this question, it doesn't matter. (Probably there is a "hacky" way round it if needed, by copying the relevant contents of the line into a temporary hidden view (i.e. output panel) and using Sublime's find API on that to ensure the anchors work as expected etc., but that is out of scope for this task.)
- The `trim_chars_around_selection` command then goes through all selections in reverse order (so the selection offsets from the beginning of the document don't change while the document is being modified by the plugin) and removes the specified number of characters from either end of the selection.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Is it possible to code it by adding that in case I press on the keys again it removes the $ again?

Comment: I have now updated my answer to make it reversible :)

Comment: you are awesome, how may I learn these things on Sublime text 3? Is there a book or tutorial videos or something I can be as good in these technical details?

Answer (score 0):

The code given by @Keith Hall could be further generalize to cut any and add any value. I will point this out here.

Suppose you want to wrap a latex file with a certain R and T that is by pressing on a combination of characters the selected string say `Tamer` would be `RTamerT` and when press on the key bindings once again it becomes `Tamer`.

```
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+q"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "contents": "R${1:$SELECTION}T", "scope": "text.tex.latex"},
    "context": [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex" },
        { "key": "text_preceding_selection", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "R" },
        { "key": "text_following_selection", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "^T" },
    ]
},

{ "keys": ["alt+shift+q"], "command": "trim_chars_around_selection", "args": { "chars_to_trim": 1, "scope": "text.tex.latex" },
    "context": [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex" },
        { "key": "text_preceding_selection", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "R" },
        { "key": "text_following_selection", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^T" },
    ]
},
```

I thought of sharing as I wanted to find a new kind of wrap that generalizes the code of Keith but do not know how to do the coding in sublime text. Trial and error have help me to find my way and thought of sharing it with you